# Método de upload em Sftp em Java nunca se encerra

Tags: java, sftp

Então, eu fiz um programa em Java usando o NetBeans para subir um arquivo "X" para um servidor SFTP e o método é funcional, mas uma vez que eu inicio o programa, ele só é encerrado a força, eu tentei varias coisas mas nd resolveu meu problema.
Meu código é:

```
public void Upload(String localfile) {
    String SFTPHOST = "example.com";
    int SFTPPORT = 22;
    String SFTPUSER = "user";
    String SFTPPASS = "pass";
    String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/var/";

    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
        File f = new File(localfile);
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
        channelSftp.disconnect();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Que biblioteca você está usando? Onde estão as classes `JSch`, `Session`, `Channel` e `ChannelSftp`?

Comment: Ah, já achei: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com o [exemplo](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html) no site da biblioteca, você precisa se desconectar da sessão utilizando o método `disconnect` da classe `Session`.

```
public void Upload(String localfile) {
    String SFTPHOST = "example.com";
    int SFTPPORT = 22;
    String SFTPUSER = "user";
    String SFTPPASS = "pass";
    String SFTPWORKINGDIR = "/var/";

    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;

    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        session.setPassword(SFTPPASS);
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(SFTPWORKINGDIR);
        File f = new File(localfile);
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(channelSftp != null) {
            channelSftp.disconnect();
        }
        if(session != null) {
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Po cara valeu, eu até vi que deveria usar o disconnect mas todos os jeitos que eu escrevi, eu escrevi errado, funcionou certinho! Obrigado!